# How to insert JSONB into Postgresql with Python?

Tags: python, json, postgresql, psycopg2, jsonb

I am new to python and postgresql

I've been battling just hardcoding each json line with python and I don't think this the scalable method. If someone can point me to the literature or documentation that can handle json insertion from python without hardcoding.

I've looked into COPY.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

```
import json

data = [1, [2,3], {'a': [4,5]}]
my_json = json.dumps(data)
insert_query = "insert into t (j) values (%s) returning j"
cursor.execute(insert_query, (my_json,))
print (cursor.fetchone()[0])
```

Output:

```
[1, [2, 3], {'a': [4, 5]}]
```

Comment: Works like a charm! And don't forget `conn.autocommit = True` or `conn.commit` to see the actual results in database.

Answer (score 3):

With dataset + psycopg2

```
import dataset

def construct_pg_url(postgres_user='postgres', postgres_password='', postgres_host='localhost', postgres_port='5432', postgres_database='postgres'):
    PG_URL = "postgresql://" + postgres_user + ":" + postgres_password + '@' + postgres_host + ':' + postgres_port + '/' + postgres_database
    return PG_URL

pgconn = dataset.Database(
             url=construct_pg_url(),
             schema='my_schema'
)
table = pgconn['my_table']
rows = [dict(foo='bar', baz='foo')] * 10000
table.insert_many(rows)
```