# Nested Json data to postgresql using python

Tags: json, python-3.x, postgresql

How can i import my json file to a postgresql using python my data will look likes

```
 {
"blocked_by": false,
"blocking": false,
"contributors_enabled": false,
"created_at": "Thu Dec 17 06:32:35 +0000 2020",
"default_profile": true,
"default_profile_image": false,
"description": "seo",
"entities": {
  "description": {
    "urls": []
  }
},
"favourites_count": 12,
"follow_request_sent": false,
"followers_count": 56,
"following": false,
"friends_count": 1344,
"geo_enabled": false,
"has_extended_profile": true,
"id": 1339458394508374018,
"id_str": "1339458394508374018",
"is_translation_enabled": false,
"is_translator": false,
"lang": null,
"listed_count": 3,
"live_following": false,
"location": "",
"muting": false,
"name": "katheryn myle",
"notifications": false,
"profile_background_color": "F5F8FA",
"profile_background_image_url": null,
"profile_background_image_url_https": null,
"profile_background_tile": false,
"profile_image_url": "http://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/1343124937389842432/30cfUmGe_normal.jpg",
"profile_image_url_https": "https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/1343124937389842432/30cfUmGe_normal.jpg",
"profile_link_color": "1DA1F2",
"profile_sidebar_border_color": "C0DEED",
"profile_sidebar_fill_color": "DDEEF6",
"profile_text_color": "333333",
"profile_use_background_image": true,
"protected": false,
"screen_name": "KatherynMyle",
"status": {
  "contributors": null,
  "coordinates": null,
  "created_at": "Tue Apr 05 10:17:04 +0000 2022",
  "entities": {
    "hashtags": [],
    "symbols": [],
    "urls": [
      {
        "display_url": "twitter.com/i/web/status/1\u2026",
        "expanded_url": "https://twitter.com/i/web/status/1511286791319564293",
        "indices": [
          117,
          140
        ],
        "url": "shortened url"
      }
    ],
    "user_mentions": [
      {
        "id": 2247373052,
        "id_str": "2247373052",
        "indices": [
          0,
          12
        ],
        "name": "GDevelop",
        "screen_name": "GDevelopApp"
      }
    ]
  },
  "favorite_count": 0,
  "favorited": false,
  "geo": null,
  "id": 1511286791319564293,
  "id_str": "1511286791319564293",
  "in_reply_to_screen_name": "GDevelopApp",
  "in_reply_to_status_id": null,
  "in_reply_to_status_id_str": null,
  "in_reply_to_user_id": 2247373052,
  "in_reply_to_user_id_str": "2247373052",
  "is_quote_status": false,
  "lang": "en",
  "place": null,
  "retweet_count": 0,
  "retweeted": false,
  "source": "<a href=\"https://mobile.twitter.com\" rel=\"nofollow\">Twitter Web App</a>",
  "text": "@GDevelopApp Hello\nHow are you fine I am a link builder and we are selling links and posts on high-quality sites if\u2026 ",
  "truncated": true
},
"statuses_count": 382,
"time_zone": null,
"translator_type": "none",
"url": null,
"utc_offset": null,
"verified": false,
"withheld_in_countries": []
```

I want to create a table with it have ing the index or key name as the column name and also i want only some index data from it not all (like utc _offset,place,etc.).so i want to insert the specific data i wanted to postgresql
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1OkJFfHyU4Eb-V3mrU2qJ_jwBaQQkunJa/view?usp=drivesdk this is the json file

Comment: What did you try? - was there something that didn't work? - did you serialize json as an object? - did you try to connect to the database?

Answer (score 0):

Your question is very vague and I can't come up with a short answer except this one:

pSQL does support JSON as a data type:

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-json.html

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html

You could just store the whole json as a single json element and select/convert/whatever within postgre later on.

[How to insert JSONB into Postgresql with Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46374367/how-to-insert-jsonb-into-postgresql-with-python)